# Commits using tortoisegit not showing up in sourceforge repository

Tags: tortoisegit, sourceforge

I set up tortoise git to commit to my sourceforge repository. It does commit -> master, shows everything as fine, but nothing is showing up on sourceforge. It was set up using the recommended command line procedure using git as sourceforge listed (although it shows up as "author unknown", another problem). Where the heck is it commiting to?

Scott Moore

Answer (score 1):

Commits are all local until you "Push" to the remote. The local repo is on your computer in whatever folder you cloned into.

The unknown author thing is probably because you haven't told TortisGit who you are (check settings for the name and email values).

Comment: That's got it, and now it is also committing under my name. So here we go with a new paradygm, I guess. If it fixes SVN's awful branching system it's worth it. Thanks.